# How to stream files from tarfile for reading?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tarfile

I am trying to read wav files from a tarfile which is located in a bucket. Since there are a lot of files I do not want to extract those files first.

Instead, I would like to read the data from the tarfile and stream it to `wavfile.read` (from `scipy.io`)

```
with tf.gfile.Open(chunk_fp, mode='rb') as f:
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r|*') as tar:
        for member in ds_text.index.values:
            bytes = BytesIO(tar.extractfile(member))  # Obviously not working
            rate, wav_data = wavfile.read(bytes)
            # Do stuff with data ..
```

However, I am not able to get my hands on a steam for `wavfile.read` to work on.

Trying different things gets me different errors:

```
 tar.extractfile(member).seek(0)
```

> `{AttributeError}'_Stream' object has no attribute 'seekable'`

```
 tar.extractfile(member).raw.read()
```

> `{StreamError}seeking backwards is not allowed`

and so on.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I just opened the file in the wrong mode. Using `r:*` instead of `r|*` works:

```
with tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r:*') as tar:
```